# How to fix pip package installation error in pycharm windows?

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip, pycharm

Executed command :

```
pip install numpy
```

Error :

> RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Possible solution :
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at `'C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\Scripts\python.exe'`.

Command Output:

> ```
> Collecting numpy   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/1e/ff467ac56bfeaea51d4a2e72d315c1fe440b20192fea7e460f0f248acac8/numpy-1.18.2.zip
> ```
>
> Installing build dependencies: started   Installing build
>   dependencies: finished with status 'done'   Getting requirements to
>   build wheel: started   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished
>   with status 'done'
>       Preparing wheel metadata: started
>       Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
>       Complete output from command C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py
>   prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
>   C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxwuuls3z:
>       Running from numpy source directory.
>       setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
>         run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
>       Cythonizing sources
>       Processing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pxd.in
>       Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random_bit_generator.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pyx.in
>       Processing numpy/random_common.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random_generator.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random_mt19937.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random_pcg64.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random_philox.pyx
>       Processing numpy/random_sfc64.pyx
>       blas_opt_info:
>       blas_mkl_info:
>       No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>       customize MSVCCompiler
>         libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib', 'C:\']
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> blis_info:
>   libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> openblas_info:
>   libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
> get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem',
> ```
>
> 'flang']'
>       customize GnuFCompiler
>       Could not locate executable g77
>       Could not locate executable f77
>       customize IntelVisualFCompiler
>       Could not locate executable ifort
>       Could not locate executable ifl
>       customize AbsoftFCompiler
>       Could not locate executable f90
>       customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
>       Could not locate executable DF
>       customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
>       Could not locate executable efl
>       customize Gnu95FCompiler
>       Could not locate executable gfortran
>       Could not locate executable f95
>       customize G95FCompiler
>       Could not locate executable g95
>       customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
>       customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
>       Could not locate executable efort
>       Could not locate executable efc
>       customize PGroupFlangCompiler
>       Could not locate executable flang
>       don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
>   libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_blas_info:
>   libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_blas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
>   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_blas_info:
>   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> accelerate_info:
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>           Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
>           Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
>           A better performance should be easily gained by switching
>           Blas library.
>         if self._calc_info(blas):
>       blas_info:
>         libraries blas not found in ['C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib', 'C:\']
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>           Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
>           Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
>           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
>           the BLAS environment variable.
>         if self._calc_info(blas):
>       blas_src_info:
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>           Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
>           Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
>           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
>           the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
>         if self._calc_info(blas):
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
> lapack_opt_info:
> lapack_mkl_info:
>   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> openblas_lapack_info:
>   libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> openblas_clapack_info:
>   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> flame_info:
>   libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
>   libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib
>   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib
>   libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
>   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_3_10_info:
>   libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib
>   libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib
>   libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
>   libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
>   libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib
>   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib
>   libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
>   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_info:
>   libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib
>   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib
>   libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
>   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> lapack_info:
>   libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\JShaikh\\PycharmProjects\\sample\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>           Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
>           Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
>           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
>           the LAPACK environment variable.
>         return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
>       lapack_src_info:
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>           Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
>           Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
>           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
>           the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
>         return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274:
> ```
>
> UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
>         warnings.warn(msg)
>       running dist_info
>       running build_src
>       build_src
>       building py_modules sources
>       creating build
>       creating build\src.win32-3.8
>       creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy
>       creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy\distutils
>       building library "npymath" sources
>       LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py",
>   line 207, in 
>           main()
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py",
>   line 197, in main
>           json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py",
>   line 69, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
>           return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p3xp3ux1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
>   line 158, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
>           self.run_setup()
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p3xp3ux1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
>   line 249, in run_setup
>           super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p3xp3ux1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
>   line 143, in run_setup
>           exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'), locals())
>         File "setup.py", line 488, in 
>           setup_package()
>         File "setup.py", line 480, in setup_package
>           setup(**metadata)
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py",
>   line 171, in setup
>           return old_setup(**new_attr)
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p3xp3ux1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 144, in setup
>           return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py",
>   line 148, in setup
>           dist.run_commands()
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 966, in run_commands
>           self.run_command(cmd)
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 985, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-p3xp3ux1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\dist_info.py",
>   line 31, in run
>           egg_info.run()
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py",
>   line 26, in run
>           self.run_command("build_src")
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py",
>   line 313, in run_command
>           self.distribution.run_command(command)
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 985, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py",
>   line 146, in run
>           self.build_sources()
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py",
>   line 157, in build_sources
>           self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py",
>   line 290, in build_library_sources
>           sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
>         File "C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py",
>   line 380, in generate_sources
>           source = func(extension, build_dir)
>         File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 661, in get_mathlib_info
>           raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
>       RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Command
>   "C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:\Users\JShaikh\PycharmProjects\sample\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py
>   prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
>   C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxwuuls3z" failed with error
>   code 1 in C:\Users\JShaikh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run the command `pip install numpy` in the prompt window in `pycharm`? Try to start an anaconda prompt window and run the command there.

If you try to install `numpy` in a specific virtual environment, you can try steps below. First create your project. Then in `pycharm` interface, go to

```
File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter
```

and click the `+` sign on the right, find `numpy` and install.

Comment: i tried installing it in windows command prompt and it did get installed.For some reason it doesnt seem to install in pycharm despite trying the above step in pycharm interface

Comment: When you install a package in pycharm, the package is usually installed in a specific virtual environment you specified. To use the package, make sure you choose the corresponding virtual environment and interpreter in run/debug configuration. The configuration button is on the top right corner.